# Entity Framework TT template -> Navigation Property name based on foreign key ID

Tags: entity-framework, t4, edmx

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Phone(
PhoneId INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Phone PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PhoneId ASC))

CREATE TABLE Person(
PersonId INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
MobilePhoneId INT NOT NULL,
PhoneId INT NOT NULL,
...

CONSTRAINT PK_Person PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PersonId ASC),
CONSTRAINT FK_Projects_Phone FOREIGN KEY (PhoneId)
    REFERENCES Phone(PhoneId),
CONSTRAINT FK_Projects_MobileId FOREIGN KEY (MobilePhoneId)
    REFERENCES Phone(PhoneId),
...
```

I am using EF an I would like to generate navigation properties based on the foreign keys, removing the Id part, so I would like to have navigation properties Phone and MobilePhone. I tried to debug, but I did not find where are the foreign keys stored.Please help with the TT template: where and what shoult I modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by edit edmx in designer or by editing T4 template. When you want to edit T4 template (your model .tt file) try to modify this:

```
public string NavigationProperty(NavigationProperty navProp)
{
    var endType = _typeMapper.GetTypeName(navProp.ToEndMember.GetEntityType());
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "{0} {1} {2} {{ {3}get; {4}set; }}",
        AccessibilityAndVirtual(Accessibility.ForNavigationProperty(navProp)),
        navProp.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many ? ("ICollection<" + endType + ">") : endType,
        _code.Escape(navProp),
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(navProp)),
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(navProp)));
}
```

in this way:

```
public string NavigationProperty(NavigationProperty navProp)
{
    var navigationPropertyName = _code.Escape(navProp);
    var match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(navigationPropertyName, "^(?<a>.+)Id$");
    if(match.Success)
        navigationPropertyName = match.Groups[1].Value;

    var endType = _typeMapper.GetTypeName(navProp.ToEndMember.GetEntityType());
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "{0} {1} {2} {{ {3}get; {4}set; }}",
        AccessibilityAndVirtual(Accessibility.ForNavigationProperty(navProp)),
        navProp.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many ? ("ICollection<" + endType + ">") : endType,
        navigationPropertyName,
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(navProp)),
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(navProp)));
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. `_code.Escape(navProp)` will contain the already refactored navigation property name, so for a `private long RequestorId` it will already be `User` in order to generate the default `public virtual User User {get;set;}`. So at this point in the TT-File, there is no more trace of the underlaying long property ending with `Id`. Your code example simly does nothing ;)

Comment: Also just modifying the TT file doesn't impact the name displayed in the EDMX-Diagram. The correct solution would be to modify the default names created in the EDMX File. The TT File then doesn't need to be modified at all, because it will simply use the name outlined in the EDMX.